# Rename [hittest] tag to [hit-test]?

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, retag-request

While removing some unnecessary tags from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874155/how-do-i-get-the-cell-from-a-table-layout-panel-vb-net), I checked to see if there were any relevant tags I could add back in. One that I thought of was for hit testing because that's essentially what he's wanting. But, when I started entering it, I noticed 2 things.

1. The tag has only been used on 433 questions. This may be a simple case of more people not prioritizing it as a key topic of their question.
2. It's worded as [hittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hittest). It looks like some type of invented word about hitting.

I think this one would work better if it was renamed as something like **hit-test** or **hit-testing**. Obviously this is low priority compared to some of the others, but it just jumped out at me as weird.

Comment: [HitTest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.HitTest) is a keyword in Delphi. A keyword that does sometimes confuse its users.

Comment: That would make sense except the description is: "Hit-testing (hit detection, picking, or pick correlation) is the process of determining whether a given object intersects another given object shape, line, or curve drawn on the screen." <-- Even that uses the hyphenated version.

Comment: I had a look at the Delphi questions tagged with [tag:hittest]. There's not that many. As far as Delphi is concerned, I think we can do this renaming without causing serious trouble.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that the generic term is "hit testing", which would be styled as "hit-testing" (or "hit-test") in the Stack Overflow tagging system (since tag names cannot contain spaces), what you failed to consider in this proposal is that many programming frameworks have a class or function named "HitTest". As such, it makes the most sense for this tag to continue to exist as [hittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hittest), so I'm declining this proposal.

In the interest of completeness, the tags [hit-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hit-test) and [hit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hit-testing) now exist as synonyms.